# TortoiseHg and multiple tags

Tags: tags, tortoisehg

Is it possible to assign multiple tags to commits using TortoiseHg? Currently, I can set only one tag to a particular commit, Looks like TortoiseHg doesn't allow more than one tag. So, is it possible to have more than one tag for a particular commit? and if so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TortoiseHG definitely supports this.
I just tried it with v 2.0.4:

[image: two tags on one commit]

What exactly makes you think TortoiseHG doesn't support this?
Do you get an error message when you try it?

Which version of TortoiseHg are you using? Maybe you're using an older version and they added this feature later? Try upgrading to the current version.

---

**EDIT:**

Davita, now I understand your problem.
You are right, when you right-click on the commit, you can only enter one tag in the tag window.
The trick is that you need to open the tag window several times in a row:

- right click the commit and select "Tag"
- enter "first tag" into the window and save
- right click the commit and select "Tag" **again**
- enter "second tag" into the window and save

Comment: I think, @Davita asked about "More than tag in **one** commit"

Comment: I don't think so. The question says "Is it possible to assign multiple tags to commits" and not "...to assign multiple tags in **one** `Added tag...` commit".

Comment: maybe, but I have personal magic skill to guess on what *user asked* what **he wanted and thought to ask**

Comment: Okay obviously I didn't know about your magical abilities ;-) Let's wait and see what he says!

Comment: @Christian, thanks for this answer. Actually, I'm using newer version of TortoiseHG :-) 2.1.3. Could you please tell me how you write several tags in "Tags" window? I right click the commit, select "Tag..." from menu and in the window, I can enter only one tag. Maybe I should separate them with a character. I tried comma and whitespace, neither worked. Thanks again

Comment: @ChristianSpecht, Thank you so much. I spent 1 hour trying to figure out what was wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is not exactly user-friendly, but instead a bit more repo-friendly.

I'm opening ".hgtags" file with a text editor and copying the commit hash via HGWorkbench and pasting it to a new line following with the tag name. If I want to add a new tag for the same commit, do the same with a different tag name.

It's like

```
c03d4783349be42b34732bef43fbd6315687bc54 SuperCoolTag
c03d4783349be42b34732bef43fbd6315687bc54 AnotherSuperCoolTag
```

With this method you can add multiple tags to multiple commits in just one commit.

If you add lines like below, you'll have a tag for the first and second commit and three tags for the third commit.

```
da977229def08ae393c48b0b4239118fd31dbe68 TAG-01
d42f2d88057f115e4f53e0f691465fec69264507 TAG-02
1e3e8603aadb08792dd7a43d6859b2e239597c4b TAG-03
1e3e8603aadb08792dd7a43d6859b2e239597c4b TAG-04
1e3e8603aadb08792dd7a43d6859b2e239597c4b TAG-05
```

I tried some methods within the HGWorkbench Tag Window to do the same, but none of them worked.